# Retrieving Data from App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am a beginner in GAE and my application is doing the insert, but is not returning datafrom database. No error appears in the log. 
What is wrong?

Follows my Factory class:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class EMFService {

    public static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMFService(){}

    public static EntityManagerFactory get()
    {
        return emfInstance;
    }
}
```

Follows my Select class:

```
public List<Pessoa> listPessoas()
{
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    List<Pessoa> lista;

    try
    {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Pessoa p");
        lista = (List<Pessoa>) q.getResultList();

    }
    finally
    {
        em.close();
    }


    return lista;

}
```

Follows my JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Pessoas</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Idade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${pessoas}" var="pessoa">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${pessoa.nome}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pessoa.idade}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Watch your case in your vars in the template.  "pessoa" should be "Pessoa"

Comment: In addition to any errors in your code, if your write an entity and immediately query for it, it may not show up for a while. Read up on eventual consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the cases of the variables in the datastore matches the cases of those in the JSP page.That is, since it's `"Pessoa"` in the datastore,it should also be `"Pessoa"` in your JSP page.Also,you should use Firebug to debug your application.Use `console.log()` to see what is being returned from the datastore.